# Appropriate uses for Venn diagrams and Tree diagrams

Tags: probability, trees

I am really confused with expressing different types of events using probability trees and venn diagrams.

Is it possible to represent dependent events using a venn diagram? I know it can be shown using a tree diagram because you can work out the $P(A|B)$ but surely this can't be represented using a venn diagram?? Or do you have to work out the probability yourself because does the venn diagram show the actual probability or only the frequency of events?

And can you represent not mutually exclusive events using a tree digram? Or is this only possible for venn diagrams because there's no intersection area in the tree diagram.

Much appreciated if someone can explain.

Comment: A practical consideration is that, even with as few as $4$ events, it becomes difficult to draw Venn diagrams that show all the possible intersections clearly.

Comment: 1. Here's my explanation: [interpreting Independence in the context of Venn diagrams](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4225537/21813).  2. "*can you represent not mutually exclusive events using a tree diagram*" Of course: after all, all independent events are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, you can represent both dependent and independent events using both Venn and tree diagrams. However, tree diagrams are useful when you are considering sequential events, or when you want to conceptualize an event as sequential. By this I mean that you can conseptualize simultaneous events as if they are occuring after one another and then draw this in a tree diagram. Sorry for the short reply.

Answer (score 0):

Venn diagram logic explaination through image.

[image]