# Are two events independent, if occurrence of one event alters possible outcomes of the other's, but still maintains the same probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's assume a group of $80$ friends where $40$ of them plays baseball, $20$ of them plays football and $10$ of them plays both the game. Without any further information, if a random person is chosen, the probability of him playing football is $20/80 = 1/4$

Now let's say, we introduce one more information that the chosen person plays baseball. Now the sample space is halved (currently having only $40$ people) but so is the event space (currently $10$). So probability stays the same ($1/4$)

This example was shown to me by one of my friends and he claimed, here `One person playing baseball` and `One person playing football` is independent of each other. Because the occurrence of one event is not changing other's probability.

But I thought, if one event reduces other's possible outcomes (Here $10$ friends leaves the equation when I apply condition), how can they be considered independent.

If these events are indeed independent, the same example with different numbers, would surely change the probability. Will the same example then be considered having dependent events?

The Wikipedia article on [Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) says,

> If P(A|B) = P(A), then events A and B are said to be independent: in
> such a case, knowledge about either event does not alter the
> likelihood of each other

Then should I always calculate the answer of any probability question to determine what formula to use? Then how will I get to the answer in the first place?

#### Edit

Fine tuned terminologies to match with what I wanted to say

Comment: A classic example of independent events is something like "roll an even number from a standard dice" and "roll a number greater than or equal to 3" which are independent and one restricts the sample space of the other (as in your question).

Comment: Okay, let's assume we are asked for an even number and a number **strictly greater than** 3. Then you will find that $P(A∩B)$ and $P(A).P(B)$ are no longer equal. Now will you say that this same exact setup (of the 2 dice) are now dependent?

Comment: Of course now they are dependent. Restricting the sample space has nothing to do with being dependent or independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, these events are independent. The definition of independent events only refers to the probabilities, not sample spaces: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

You could argue that for any (nontrivial) events, conditioning on one event always changes the other's sample space. For example, if we roll two dice and define $A$ to be the event "the first die shows $6$" and $B$ to be the event "the second die shows $6$", then these are clearly independent. However, the real sample space for either event is all $36$ possible outcomes, and the event space for $B$ is $\{(1,6),(2,6),\ldots,(6,6)\}$. Once you condition on $A$, the sample space for $B$ changes to $\{(6,1),(6,2),\ldots,(6,6)\}$, and the event space changes to just $(6,6)$, but the probability hasn't changed and that is what makes them independent.

---

In a comment you suggested that the real sample space associated to event $B$ is just a set of size $6$ (the roll on the second die), and conditioning on $A$ doesn't change that. But you can do exactly the same thing with your initial example.

Divide the $80$ people into $20$ groups of $4$. Do this in such a way that the first $10$ groups all have four baseball players, one of whom also plays football, and the remaining $10$ groups have no baseball players but one football player each. The numbers you gave ensure this is always possible.

Now number the groups $1,\ldots,20$ and number the people in each group $1,2,3,4$, with the football player in each group being number $1$. You can choose a uniformly random person by choosing a number from $1,\ldots,20$ to pick a group, then independently choosing a number from $1,2,3,4$ to select a person from that group.

Now the event "plays baseball" is "the first number is at most $10$". The event "plays football" is "the second number is $1$". This is now exactly the same as the dice example - one event only refers to the first number and the other to the second.

Comment: So changing the numbers will make the events dependent?

Comment: I was talking about the sample space of the other event, not the entire sample space. If this sounds confusing (my apologies), by the sample space of the other event I meant, what are all the possibilities from that set alone. Like in the dice example, even after conditioning, the other dice can roll anything, (1,2,3,4,5,6). Thus they are independent

Comment: The sample space still has size $36$. Each event is just a subset of size $6$. The notion of an event having a smaller sample space doesn't make sense. I'll edit my answer to try to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Good question!

When considering **whether events $X$ and $Y$ are independent**, the correct intuition is to ask whether the knowledge that $X$ happens changes the *probability* of $Y$—not whether it restricts how $Y$ can happen.

Consider this experiment: flip two fair coins, letting $H_1$ be the
event that the first coin lands on Heads, and $X$ be the event that
the coins land on different sides. Then $$ P\left(H_1 \cap
X\right)=\frac14=P(H_1)\:P(X);$$ i.e., Events $H_1$ and $X$ are, by definition, **independent**. *Despite this*, the knowledge that $H_1$ happens has reduced the number of ways that $X$ can happen: one of $X$'s outcomes, $TH,$ is no longer possible.

Summarising:

> Let $P(A)\neq0.$
>
> Then events $A$ and $B$ are **independent** iff knowing that $A$ happens doesn't change $B$'s **probability**.

[Visualising independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4225537/21813).

Comment: So to summarize, since independent events are **defined** from the exact value of the probability, configuration does not matter.

Comment: @irtiazkabir Yes, roughly speaking: pairwise independence is a state based on whether the quantitative chance is affected, not on whether the collection of possible outcomes is changed