# Conditional probability of a variable, with more than one condition and where some variables are independent from each other

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Good afternoon,

I am a student of statistics and I am taking a course in Bayesian Statistics but I had problems understanding how to derive one of the formulas.

There are three random variables a, z, y with *z and y independent* (which means P(z∩y)=P(z)*P(y)).

I have to show that:
$P(a|z,y)=\frac{P(z|a)*P(a|y)}{P(z)}$
with $P(a|z,y)$ meaning "probability of **a** given **z** and **y**"

What I have done so far:

- with:
  $P(z,y|a)=\frac{P(z,y,a)}{P(a)}=\frac{P(z|y,a)*p(y,a)}{P(a)}=\frac{P(z|y,a)*p(a|y)*P(y))}{P(a)}$

then:

$P(a|z,y)=\frac{(P(z,y|a)*P(a)}{P(z,y)}$
$=\frac{\frac{P(z|y,a)*p(a|y)*P(y)}{P(a)}*P(a)}{P(z)*P(y)}$
$=\frac{P(z|y,a)*P(a|y)}{P(z)}$

I do not understand how to show that *P(z|a,y)* is equal to *P(z|a)* when z and y are independent.

Thank you for your help.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $z$ and $y$ independent.
>
> I do not understand how to show that $P(z|a,y)$ is equal to $P(z|a).$

- $P(Z|A,Y)=P(Z|A)$ is **not** in general true; e.g., in the following
  counterexample $$P(Z|A,Y)=1\neq\frac12=P(Z|A).$$

  [image]
- However, when $P(A),P(Y),P(Z)\neq0$ and $A,Y,Z$ are
  mutually-independent events, then the equality is true, since
  $$P(Z|A,Y)=P(Z|A)\\\iff
     \frac{P(A,Y,Z)}{P(A,Y)}=\frac{P(A,Z)}{P(A)}\\\iff
     \frac{P(A)P(Y)P(Z)}{P(A)P(Y)}=\frac{P(A)P(Z)}{P(A)}\\\iff 1=1.$$

P.S. I wrote this [related Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4269525/21813), to a Question asked around the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In my case y and z are independent just conditioned on a. I thought it was clear but now I think I should have written it explicitly. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jack Yes you did specify that in your Question, and I *did* take note of that (read my first line). The counterexample that I have given is indeed as per your specification.