# Proving the probability of independency of the events formula by Venn Diagram?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

We know that if two or more events are independent of each other then the probability of happening of both is simply the product of individual probabilities , i was thinking if its possible to show/prove it using just the venn diagram of the possible events taking place ? How the individual multiplication being arrived that i would like to get from the Venn diagram .

Comment: You may want to make a "rectangle" type diagram like $$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}
(1,3) & (4,3) & (8,3) & (3, 3)\\
(1,2) & (4,2) & (8, 2)& (3, 2) \\
(1,0) & (4, 0) & (8, 0) & (3, 0)
\end{array}
\right]$$ which can represent equally likely ordered pair outcomes $(X,Y)$ where the value of $X$ does not depend on the value $Y$.

Comment: You probably do not want a Venn diagram to illustrate this, but something more like https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/380791/2958

Comment: You need not only Venn diagram but power of each set in it (measured in equiprobable elementary events) to check independence.

Comment: Understood thanks @Michael , Henry , Ivan

Comment: Please check out [Visualising independence of events](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4225537/21813).

Comment: Amazing explanation Sir thanks @ryang

Comment: @Orion_Pax Thanks, and you're welcome. And this elaborates on a point raised in the previous link: [Mutually exclusive typically implies dependence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4419308/21813).