# $A,B, C$ are independent $\implies (A \cup B)$ and $(B \cup C)$ are independent?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, independence

Given that $A,B, C$ are independent events, I am trying to prove that $A \cup B$ and $B \cup C$ are independent.

$$P((A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C)) \\= P(B \cup (A \cap C)) \\= P(B) + P(A \cap C) - P(A \cap B \cap C) \\= P(B) + P(A)P(C) - P(A)P(B)P(C)\\ = P(B) + P(A)P(C) \left(1 - P(B) \right).$$

This clearly does not equal $P(A \cup B)P(B \cup C).$ **How do I find an explicit counterexample to the claim that $A \cup B$ and $B \cup C$ are independent events?** I am struggling because of the condition that $A,B,C$ must be independent.

Comment: Why do you say "clearly"?  If it is clear that these are not the same, then you should be able to design a counterexample.  Try the simplest example...let $A,B,C$ represent the outcome of the tosses of three independent fair coins.

Comment: @lulu could I use numbers instead, so like $\Omega =$ {$0,1$}, as this is easier for me ?

Comment: Absolutely.  you have three ordered numbers, each of which is either $0$ or $1$ with equal probability (independent of the others). $A$ is the event the first one is $1$, and so on.

Comment: @lulu so I will let A be event $1$st is heads, B $2$nd heads, and C$3$rd heads. $P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = $\frac{1/2}$. Then each individual event is independent since for example P($A \cap B$) = P(HHH,HHT) = $\frac{1}{4}$ = $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, those are three independent events.  Good.  Now you need to analyze $A\cup B$ and $B\cup C$.

Comment: @lulu Then for $P( (A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C)) = P((HHH, HHT, HTH, THH, THT)) = \frac{5}{8}$. Did I calculate this probability correctly? And then this is not equal to $(\frac{6}{8})^2 = \frac{9}{16}$

Comment: Right.  The only events not in that intersection are $HTT, TTH,TTT$.  Your analysis looks good, and complete.  If you are so inclined, I suggest posting your own solution below.  The site prefers not to leave questions unanswered, and if you write it all out, users here can check it.

Comment: The simplest case is just to let $A$ and $C$ be events that never happen, so they're obviously independent of anything.

Comment: @lulu Can you please check my answer below ?

Comment: I'd have thought $A\cup B, B\cup C$ are always dependent as they both contain $B$ (except if $B=\emptyset$ or $B\subset A,C$).

Comment: @JMP But no-disjointedness does not imply dependence (in fact, it is disjointedness that implies dependence); for example, in Universe $U_3$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4225537/21813), events $X$ and $Y$ have a common outcome and are independent. (In general, it is mutual exclusivity, not independence, that is immediately obvious from a Venn diagram.)

Comment: *non-disjointedness

Answer (score 1):

Consider an experiment of tossing two coins where each outcome is uniform. We have $\Omega =$ {H,T}$^2$. Label events:

$A =$ Event that first coin toss is heads. $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$

$B =$ Event that second coin toss is heads $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$

$C = \emptyset$ $P(C) = 0$

Check that $A,B,C$ are independent.

$P(A \cap B) = P({HH}) = \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} $

$P(A \cap C) = P(\emptyset) = 0 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0 $

$P(B \cap C) = P(\emptyset) = 0 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0 $

$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(\emptyset) = 0 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0 $

Now, check whether $A \cup B$ and $B \cup C$ are independent.

$P((A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C)) = P({HH,TH}) = \frac{1}{2}$. However, this is not equal to $P(A \cup B) \cdot P(B \cup C) = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{8}$, so not independent.

Comment: You were right in the comments...$P(A\cup B)=\frac 34=P(B\cup C)$ so the product is $\left(\frac 34\right)^2=\frac 9{16}$.  Same conclusion, of course.  Besides that, it looks good.

Comment: @lulu $P(B \cup C) = \frac{3}{4}$ ? Are you sure ? The only outcomes for that are HH and TH

Comment: @lulu I think you are getting confused with my previous events in the comments. They have been labelled differently in my answer.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  Personally, I prefer the other example..."degenerate" events always make independence look a bit artificial.  After all, if $E$ has probability $0$ then $E$ is independent from itself, which seems...unintuitive.  But, it's a perfectly good example nonetheless.

Comment: @lulu Okay thanks for your help. Should I accept my answer ?

Comment: Sure!  Why not? $\quad$

Answer (score 0):

Distilling the OP's counterexample in the self-answer: consider a single toss of a fair coin, and let $A,B$ and $C$ be the events of obtaining 2 Tails, a Tail, and 3 Tails, respectively.

Then $A \cup B=\{\text{tail}\}=B \cup C,$

and $P(A \cup B)P(B \cup C)=\frac14\ne\frac12=P\big((A \cup B)\cap(B \cup C)\big).$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that with a few inependent events A,B,C the equality is satisfied:
$${P(B)+P(A)P(C)(1-P(B))=P(A\cup B)P(B\cup C) (I)}$$

From set theory knowing that:
$${A \cup B = A \cup (B \setminus (A \cap B))}$$
$${P(A \cup B)=P(A \cup (B \setminus (A \cap B)))}$$

Since sets {${A}$} and {${B \setminus (A \cap B)}$} do not have any common elements, then we can use that ${P(X \cup Y)=P(X)+P(Y)}$, resulting in:
$${P(A \cup B)=P(A \cup (B \setminus (A \cap B)))=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)}$$ while ${P(A \setminus B)=P(A)-P(B)}$ is also true while ${A \supset B}$.

Then rewriting the right side of the (I) equation we get:
$${P(A\cup B)P(B\cup C)=(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B))(P(B)+P(C)-P(B \cap C))}$$
$${=(P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B))(P(B)+P(C)-P(B)P(C))}$$
$${=P(A)P(C)[(1-2P(B)+P^2(B))]+P(B)[(P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(B)P(C)-P(A)P(B))] (II)}$$

Now we can find the equality between (I) equation's left side and (II):
$${P(B): 1=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(B)P(C)-P(A)P(B)}$$
$${P(A)P(C): 1-P(B)=1-2P(B)+P^2(B) (III)}$$

From the (III) equation we have:
$${0=-P(B)+P^2(B)=P(B)(-1+P(B))}$$

Which means it is forced that P(B) is either 0 or 1 and it obviuosly satisfies (I) equation.

So the condition for your statement to be true, ${P(B)=0 \lor 1}$ have to be true.